# What can I do if drain alignment doesn't allow enough space for p-trap?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, drain-waste-vent

I'm remodeling my bathroom. The sink drainage come up from the floor. The alignment between that and the drain coming from the sink doesn't have enough space for a p-trap to be installed so it just falls into place and connects the two (prior to remodel there was no p-trap).

I was thinking having a 45 degree pipe come out of the sink, forward then down, then attach the p-trap, and that would allow enough space for overflow to go back and down to floor drain pipe. My crude image of what I mean, circled in red.[image: PTrapImage]

Would this allow for proper drainage?

Comment: Have you had any sewer gas smells up to this point?  This is perhaps unlikely, but what is the possibility that there is already a P-trap in the floor?  If there is, you don't need to add another trap above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you purchase a P-trap from the hardware store, you'll end up with these pieces (or something similar).

[image: P-Trap pieces]

You'll also want to pick up a 1-1/2 in. PVC 90° slip-joint elbow while you're there.

[image: 1-1/2 in. PVC 90° slip-joint elbow]

You'll then want to connect the pieces something like this...

[image: Connect these pieces]

You'll then have to twist the pieces around, until you can get them to fit together. You'll end up with something similar to this.

[image: twisted p-trap][image: twisted p-trap]

Though I'm not sure this is code compliant anymore.

In the 2003 version of International Residential Code (IRC), there was this section.

> ## International Residential Code 2003
>
> ### Chapter 31 Vents
>
> #### Section P3105 Fixture Vents
>
> **P3105.3 Vertical leg for waste fixture drains.** A vertical leg (see Figure P3105.3) is permitted within a fixture drain of a waste fixture in accordance with the following criteria:
>
> 1. Minimum trap diameter shall be in accordance with Table P3201.7.
> 2. The diameter of Section A shall be equal to the diameter of the trap.
> 3. The length of Section A shall not be less than 8 inches (203 mm) and in accordance with Table P3105.1.
> 4. The diameter of Section B shall be one pipe size larger than the diameter of Section A.
> 5. The length of Section B shall not be more than 36 inches (914 mm).
> 6. The diameter of Section C shall be one pipe size larger than the diameter of Section B.
> 7. The total length of Section A and Section C shall not exceed the distance allowed in Table P3105.1.
> 8. Bends shall be the diameter of the largest connected section.
>
> [image: FIGURE P3105.3 VERTICAL LEG FIXTURE DRAIN SCHEMATIC]

However, in the 2006 version, this section is gone.

Comment: Not allowed by code for new construction, the water seal can be siphoned out by too high a water flow in an s-trap arrangement. For old construction, be aware of the water siphon effect and if you empty a sink full of water, run a pint of water through after the bowl empties. And since it didn't have a trap before, it's better than no trap at all.

Answer (score 0):

When the drain goes vertically like this, it is often called an S-trap, since it is shaped like a letter S instead of a letter P.

[image: drain S-trap]

That center connection in the S-trap is a swivel.  You can do it without the 45-degree section if you rotate the center connection. You can see that in this example:

[image: angled S-trap]

The more you rotate the center joint, the closer together the input and output are.

Will this be visible to the room, or enclosed in a cabinet?  If it is visible, I can imagine perhaps wanting the aesthetics of a straight symmetrical drain.  If it's hidden inside, just use the S-trap without the 45-degree lead-in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, from what I have read, it seems that s traps are heavily deprecated due to siphoning. Is this not the case in this configuration?

Comment: S-traps are not code compliant in most location.

Comment: That's a different question.  If you don't have a drain in the wall with a vent stack, it's not a P-trap.  If the drain pipe is in the floor, you have an S-trap.  In either of the proposed configurations, either your original with the 45 or my suggestion without, both are absolutely S-trap configurations.  Even if the S-trap does siphon, it can't be worse than the previous no-trap drain.  You can try putting the trap as low as possible, so that the sink-to-trap section is the longest, and the trap-to-floor section is shortest, to reduce the siphon-prone drop part.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use an AAV... S-traps have long ago been illegal for the siphon issue that you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that with an AAV this is no longer considered an S-trap? I assumed just the straight leg (the horizontal pipe in the image) was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

Mine didn't line up.  I did the following, but check for your local code....

[image: How I did it]