# P-trap installation - faucet tailpipe close to stubout

Tags: plumbing, p-trap

Installing a new vanity and luckily the faucet tailpipe remains centered on the stubout, but they are very close to each other depth-wise. Maybe 2” above the Stu out and 2” in front of it. Not really seeing a way I can fit the trap and trap arm all in there. I’m sure there is a good solution for this without having to run some crazy corkscrew route. And from what I gather a flexible p trap is not a good answer for many reasons. Hoping you all can make some suggestions. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That;'s actually less "lucky" than you think - some sideways offset makes it easier to get the parts to fit (by rotating until they line up) without gymnastics and extra parts.

Comment: Or this? [What can I do if drain alignment doesn't allow enough space for p-trap?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43875/what-can-i-do-if-drain-alignment-doesnt-allow-enough-space-for-p-trap)

Answer (score 4):

Use 90 degree or 45 degree elbow where the pipe comes out of the wall and orient the the dip of the trap sideways and then the outlet across into the elbow,

It's all about slope, P traps don't have to look like a "P" when installed so long as the slope is good.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when the tailpiece is too close to the wall, the trap is installed with the J-bend swinging forwardish, but this only works when the stubout is offset and the arm has a clear path back.

You still might be able to make this work with a [tubular offset](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-1-1-2-in-Plastic-Slip-Joint-Double-Off-set/1000383333). Maybe try cutting it in half and turning 45 out of the stubout. But make sure to place your 45 so that you're still in range of the J-bend.